# Remove home menu item from lightning community navigation menu

Tags: community, navigation

I'm trying to remove the Home menu item from the navigation bar in our customer community.  I've already tried the CSS hack posted on here previously but couldn't get it to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  We'd like the landing page to be the account record detail page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ootb, you cant really remove it. Yes you can hide it using CSS however, if there is a community Update that changes the CSS class, then your CSS rule is most likely going to break, re-exposing the Home Page.

This leaves you with the following options:

- [Create Custom Theme Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)
- [Build a Custom Navigation Menu](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/communities_theme_layout/steps/nav_menu)

More on all of these topics at: [Customize the Look and Feel of a Lightning Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize.htm)

Basically, you can create your custom theme for your home page, and have a custom navigation menu that does not display, it is a lot more work, but in the long run, more compliant code wise, and adheres to best practices.

You will most likely want to setup your home page with data from an Account record detail page OR find some way of redirecting users to the account record detail page using navigaion events when thepage loads.

Comment: Yes, theme components are a very useful feature even though it is a bigger learning curve and initial build time than the old CSS hacks.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help - not quite the quick fix answer I was hoping for but I'll give it a go.