# Remove More Option From Experience Cloud Navigation menu

Tags: lightning-experience, experience-cloud, digital-experience, navigation-menu

[image]

Whenever we zoom in the More Dropdown comes automatically.. Is there any way to avoid it
I mean avoid slds-hidden class from getting added to the menu items.

I have an idea to write resize event on the document and for every resize if the class is present then remove it.. not sure if that's an ideal solution.

I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove home menu item from lightning community navigation menu](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226366/remove-home-menu-item-from-lightning-community-navigation-menu)

Comment: hi @identigral, it's a little different I don't want the home removed.
I want the MORE option to be removed, without hiding it via CSS,

Comment: Using custom navigation should be an option here but that's more work than hiding this with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a media queries in css of experience builder. You can find the option to edit css under theme menu.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .more-button {
    //set hidden here.
  }
}
```

Go through this document for more details
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp